# Why child component didnt get parent's props with Axios in React

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

### I solve it with a simple flag like so:

1. I added a new **flag** property on the states object: `loaded:false`
2. I update the `loaded` value to true, when i get the data, like so:

   ```
    helpers.getValues().then(results => this.setState({values:results.data,loaded:true}));
   ```
3. **And finally, inside the `render()` i first check if the `loaded==true` and then i render the ChildComponent, like so**:

   ```
   {this.state.loaded == true ? <ChildComponent values={this.state.values} name="theodore"/> : ''}
   ```

---

I am making a simple code in **React** that **gets** data with **Axios**.

The data are returned to the client , so the communication is OK.
The problem is that I pass the results data to a child component , as props, and as soon as the child component loads it asks for the **props.data** but it is empty.

### Below is the Parent component:

1. Inside the `componentDidMount` I call the axios to get the data and update the `setState` object.
2. Below, into the `render` function, I pass the results to the `ChildComponent`.

   ```
   var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
       getInitialState:function(){
           return {
               values:''
               activeTab:0
           }
       },
       componentDidMount:function(){
           helpers.getValues().then(results => this.setState({values:results.data}));
       },
       render:function(){
           return(
               <div className='container'>
                   <div className="row">
                       <div className="col-sm-8 text-center" >
                           <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
                           <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTab} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="controlled-tab-example">
                               <Tab eventKey={tabs[0].key} title={tabs[0].name}>
                                   Tab1
                                   <ChildComponent1 values={this.state.values} test="ok"/>
                               </Tab>
                               <Tab eventKey={tabs[1].key} title={tabs[1].name}>Tab2</Tab>
                           </Tabs>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           )
       }
   ```

### And here i show the ChildComponent(in a seperate js file).

Inside the **componentDidMount** I try to show the props but the object that gets it like:
**{values:'',test:'ok'}**

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount:function(){
        console.log(this.props);
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>'nothing'</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

*I guess that it is a delay issue, in which the chld component loads before the axios async returns the data from server*

Any help from someone that has dealt with a similar situation would be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Even if your child renders before the request data is returned from server, it should again render when executing the `then` block of Promise, as you are setting a value in state and react component will render on every state change.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that before, but on the childcomponent i used to do a map() to create the <li> list ,  and i got error! Maybe i should add an if statement there , i dont know. But now it works as i need it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, You'll need to add an if condition to check whether value is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing `this.state.movies`, instead of `this.state.values` to the `ChildComponent`.

**How you do it**:

```
<ChildComponent1 values={this.state.movies} test="ok"/>
```

**How it should be**:

```
<ChildComponent1 values={this.state.values} test="ok"/>
```

Comment: It is a clear async issue that we have to no permit the child component render before the results return from the server.

Comment: Okay. But in your example you don't have *movies* property in the state, but you pass it down to the child. From where do movies come?